# How to select random ID in Mysql query

Tags: mysql, database, relationship

```
SELECT e.ent_seq, 
        GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT kei.keb SEPARATOR'; ')AS kebs, 
        GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT rei.reb SEPARATOR '; ') AS rebs,
        GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT sei.mean SEPARATOR '; ') AS means,
FROM entry e
    LEFT JOIN k_ele kei ON e.entry = kei.entry
    LEFT JOIN r_ele rei ON e.entry = rei.entry
    LEFT JOIN sense se ON e.entry = se.entry 
    LEFT JOIN s_gloss_eng sei ON se.SID = sei.SID
WHERE mn_null = 1
GROUP BY e.entry
```

How to randomly select e.entry? e.entry is an int.

Comment: Sigh... http://infobot.pl/r/2bct

Answer (score 1):

```
 SELECT e.ent_seq, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT kei.keb SEPARATOR'; ')AS kebs, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT rei.reb SEPARATOR '; ') AS rebs,
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT sei.mean SEPARATOR '; ') AS means

FROM entry e

LEFT JOIN k_ele kei ON e.entry = kei.entry
LEFT JOIN r_ele rei ON e.entry = rei.entry
LEFT JOIN sense se ON e.entry = se.entry 
LEFT JOIN s_gloss_eng sei ON se.SID = sei.SID

WHERE e.ent_seq IN (SELECT jt5.jlpt5_seq FROM jlptn5 jt5
                   WHERE jt5.jlpt5_null = 0
                   ORDER BY RAND())
GROUP BY e.entry    
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 20
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this solution -

```
SELECT e.ent_seq, 
        GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT kei.keb SEPARATOR'; ')AS kebs, 
        GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT rei.reb SEPARATOR '; ') AS rebs,
        GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT sei.mean SEPARATOR '; ') AS means,
FROM (SELECT * FROM entry ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1) e
    LEFT JOIN k_ele kei ON e.entry = kei.entry
    LEFT JOIN r_ele rei ON e.entry = rei.entry
    LEFT JOIN sense se ON e.entry = se.entry 
    LEFT JOIN s_gloss_eng sei ON se.SID = sei.SID
WHERE mn_null = 1
GROUP BY e.entry
```

Add condition `WHERE mn_null = 1` to `e` table alias if `mn_null` is a field from the `entry` table.

Comment: It will be very slow if table `entry` is big

Comment: Yes, this solution is slow for big tables, but it is easy to understand. There are another solutions, and all them may be applied to this query in the same way.